# webpart contain autocomplete textbox for farm solution

Tags: 2013, web-part

Is it possible to create a webpart contain autocomplete textbox for sharepoint 2013?
I know that everything is possible but I tried many many tutorials and samples and nothing works. So if yes could you guide me to newbie tutorial ?

Note: Please if you  suggest any tutorial, that because you did try it by yourself not you just google it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done my Own really  WORK solution :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >

    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("MyFunctionName");
function MyFunctionName() {

        $("input#autocompletebox").autocomplete({ 
source: itemSource         
        });
}
</script>
```

thanks although for your response

Answer (score 0):

You should take look at TaxonomyFieldControl or TaxonomyWebTaggingControl. I am using TaxonomyWebTaggingControl for this purpose. Take a look at this blog http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/01/21/using-sharepoint-taxonomywebtaggingcontrol-control-specifying-parent-terms/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using [SPService](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)

SPServices is a jQuery library which abstracts SharePoint's Web Services and makes them easier to use. It also includes functions which use the various Web Service operations to provide more useful (and cool) capabilities. It works entirely client side and requires no server install.

[Here can you find a tutorial to create an autocomplete textbox](http://sympmarc.com/2013/10/07/spservices-stories-17-multiple-form-fields-autocomplete-for-sharepoint-20102013-using-javascript/)

Comment: after finish it I didn't get any WEBPART, which is my first purpose of the question, even though thanks for your response